# Publishing VS Code extension via Azure DevOps

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vscode-extensions

After reading [VSCode Publish Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension) docs, I've succeeded to publish a VSCode extension manually with `vsce`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to publish extensions automatically via Azure DevOps pipelines (build or release) instead of doing it manually.

I've tried to use `vsce` there but I'm getting an authentication error

> Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

Using `vsce publish -p <access_token>` is not possible because the pipeline is public and everyone can see the access token...

So, is there a way to publish a Visual Studio Code extension automatically via Azure DevOps Pipeline or even Travis CI?

Comment: And now is part of the official docs - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/continuous-integration#automated-publishing

Comment: @MoshFeu Any reason why in the docs you are publishing the extension with the Build pipeline and not the Release pipeline of Azure DevOps?

Comment: @MoshFeu I tried your steps with the Release Pipeline (instead of build). All worked fine, but when I've added a dependency it started to fail in `yarn deploy` with the error `Command failed: npm list --production --parseable --depth=99999` (my dependencies were missing). How can I solve this?

Comment: Actually I never tried to use the release pipeline. I'll try and return with my conclusions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the Personal Access Token as a secret variable, then nobody can couldn't see it.

Go to Azure DevOps to your pipeline and click on "Edit", not in the top left click on "Variables":

[image]

Now click on the `+` icon and add the variable, mark the checkbox "Keep this value secret":

[image]

Now you can use it in this way: `$(PAT)`, for example:

```
vsce publish -p $(PAT)
```

The variable value will not appear in the YAML :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to publish a Visual Studio Code extension automatically
>   via Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Of course yes!

*To have a good experience for CI/CD in Azure Devops, I recommend you store the source code in Azure Devops or Github.*

- **Build \ CI**

In build, most of work is update the version which in manifest of VSIX, build\create package. For the version increased, here I use the `counter` expression feature which supported in VSTS to achieve that:

```
counter('name', seed)
```

Use this expression in variable declaration bloc. For detailed and completed build process, refer to my sample YAML code:

```
trigger:
- '*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  VersionPatch: $[counter('versioncount', 24)]
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  BuildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  BuildConfiguration: 'Release'

name: 2.0.$(VersionPatch)

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.0.100'
    includePreviewVersions: true

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.1.0

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Update version
  inputs:
    filePath: 'Build\VersionUpdate.ps1'
    arguments: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    pwsh: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: 'tests/**/*.csproj'
    vstsFeed: '{My feed ID}'
    includeNuGetOrg: false

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
    maximumCpuCount: true
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      Build/**
      **/*.vsix
      **/*.nupkg
      README.md
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  inputs:
    artifactName: 'ExtensionDrop'
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

In UpdateVersion.ps1 file:

```
$VerbosePreference="Continue"
$version = $args[0]
if (!$version) {
    $version = "0.0.0"
}
Write-Host "This Version is: $version"
$FullPath = Resolve-Path $PSScriptRoot\..\src\Merlin.Compiler.Vsix\source.vsixmanifest
Write-Host $FullPath
[xml]$content = Get-Content $FullPath
$content.PackageManifest.Metadata.Identity.Version = $version
$content.Save($FullPath)
```

- **Release\ CD**

After build succeed, set the release pipeline for this repos. In release, use powershell script and `VsixPublisher.exe` to publish the `vsix` file.

```
$PAToken = $args[0]
$VsixPath = "$PSScriptRoot\..\src\Merlin.Compiler.Vsix\bin\Release\Merlin.Compiler.Vsix"
$ManifestPath = "$PSScriptRoot\ExtensionManifest.json"
$Installation = & "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -prerelease -format json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Path = $Installation.installationPath
$VsixPublisher = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath "VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Tools\Bin\VsixPublisher.exe" -Resolve
& $VsixPublisher publish -payload $VsixPath -publishManifest $ManifestPath -personalAccessToken $PAToken -ignoreWarnings "VSIXValidatorWarning01,VSIXValidatorWarning02,VSIXValidatorWarning08"
```

In CD, use `VsixPublisher.exe` which exist in VS to publish the `vsix` file.

---

You can set the PAToken in Variable tab, then **set it as secret**. Thus it would not be public for others. Here PAT token is a necessary one which could not be replaced by others. And also, when generate the token, need choose **All accessible organizations**. Or it will cause the permission error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Further @Shayki's answer there are some more steps because you can't just run `vsce publish -p $(PAT)`.

1. The `vsce` should be installed (can be in `devDependencies`)
2. Add a "deploy" (or name it as you like) script to the *package.json* scripts.

```
"deploy": "vsce publish -p"
```

3. Add a "publish" step in the *azure-pipeline.yml* file. the `condition` is for running the publish script only on `master` so Pull Requests will not publish. Also run it  only in Linux's build, in case you configured multiple platforms. If you configured only one (for example, windows) replace `Linux` with that platform

```
- bash: |
   echo ">>> Publish"
   yarn deploy $(token)
 displayName: Publish
 condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'))
```

[Example *azure-pipeline.yml*](https://github.com/moshfeu/vscode-compare-folders/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml#L40-L44)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!